# Odoo 10 XMLRPC - Retrieve Image

Tags: python, xml-rpc, odoo

I am trying to retrieve image from XMLRPC.

I do:

```py
record = api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'read', [[id]], {'fields': ['id', 'name', 'image']})
sub_record = dict((k, record[0][k]) for k in ('id', 'name', 'image'))
print sub_record['image']
```

If I print the image using `print sub_record['image']` then I get:

```
[...]
eSYH+sOdc3UW9XB1SzWvVCtcI0PfKdoYe9Suf/3116+mMGyhLTg/yedEprt6nOI3eNOxT9t6SzMN
Cj8tT5Lp9eqmsvmu1reytnROwdFvdWvkwsLihqqJ0+49ZW8nu9tzDb+RkT2f5tWpjpf8yZaJzyYW
SPN8f22Vnp9pr+mA7KzqwltQk8QGT02ViY6bpvBdTZqJH5uafxJcHFzPp8nB6KTYUlMq4jS3mAkm
[...]
```

So basically several carriage returns are inserted in the middle of the image base64 string.

How can I use that string to display it in an `<img>` html tag?

Do I have to remove these carriage returns first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you get the base64 string from the odoo. You don't need to modify it just add the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` content before the base64 string. Now you have to add whole updated string in image tag as below.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Also Check this https://jsfiddle.net/Xadvz/7883/ example in which I have created image from the base64 string of demo product "Ink Cartridge" for further reference.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Whit above code I get base64 with CR+LF characters (\n), and that it is not accepted as src. I had to remove those CR+LF (\n) before using data as src.

Comment: I saw the jsfiddle, I will try not to remove the CR+LF characters returned by Odoo and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

you can save the **base64** data into image using code.

```
rec = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'read', [[id]], {'fields': ['id', 'name', 'image']})
img_data = rec[0]['image']
data_id = rec[0]['id']
fh = open("/tmp/product_image-%d.png" %(data_id), "wb") #you can use imghdr to identify the image type
decoded = img_data.decode('base64')
fh.write(decoded)
fh.close()
```

and after that you can write yout code to use the file path in  tag.

Comment: Need was to use in html tag, not store to file.